# How to solve the problem that gdb exits main function with a message "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h: No such file or directory"?

Tags: c++, gdb

exit debugging log:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.cpp:6
6           cout << "hello world" << endl;
(gdb) n
hello world
7           return 0;
(gdb) n
9       }
(gdb) n
__libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x5555555551a9 <main()>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffe348) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:74
74      ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h: No such file or directory.
```

Hope to solve this problem "No such file or directory".

Comment: You want to be able to step into the source code for the runtime library? Why?

Comment: No, I'm just tired of being told that there's a bug like "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope to solve this problem

1. You don't actually have a problem, since it's unlikely that you want to step into `libc` implementation to start with, but ...
2. If you really do want to step into libc code, you need to install GIBC source, and tell GDB where that source is installed (using GDB `dir` command).

Comment: So just ignore this prompt message, and my program won't be affected by this message in the future, right?

Comment: @lanxuyang Correct. You have stepped out of `main`, so there is nothing else to debug (except possibly global destructors). You can just `continue` and your program should exit.